# Summation in AVR Assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, avr

I want to implement a routine that calculates the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to `n`. `n` is a variable stored in RAM. The result has to be stored in a **two-byte** variable in RAM, too. I'm very new in assembly programming so I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the algorithm to achieve this. So far, I've done this:

```
.DSEG

.ORG 0x100

n:  .BYTE l_n
result: .BYTE l_result

.CSEG

.ORG 0x100

SUM:
LDI XL, n               ;the direction of n is stored in XL
LD R16, X               ;now r16=n
LDI XL, LOW(result)
LDI XH, HIGH(result)    ;X points to result
CLC                     ;in case C is full with trash
LDI R17, 0x0            ;R17 = 0
LDI R18, 0x1            ;R18 = 1
CALL LOOP   
LDI R16,0
LDI R17,0
ADC R16, R17        ;if C is on when the loop finishes, then it has to be summed as well
ST X, R16
RET                 ;returns to the program that called the routine
```

I did the initialization of `R17` and `R18` because I thought that the subroutine `LOOP` should do something like increasing this numbers one by one until doing it `n` times. The thing that is complicating me the most is the fact that the result has two bytes, while each number being summed consists of just one byte. I don't know how to deal with this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is hard to follow because it is so mixed up, and you are missing the LOOP part. The key idea is to add the current one-byte number to the low byte of the result with ADD, and then add 0 to the high byte of the result with a carry, ADC. Then decrement the current one-byte and check to see if you should stop.

Comment: I got your idea, that was very clear. Thank you

Comment: (Assuming AVR8) Then again, the first sentence contains `calculates the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to n`, and there is a well known formula for that. Whether or not this can be exploited simply depends on the availability of the MUL instruction.

Comment: homework? As @greybeard mentions, there is a sum formula **S = n(n+1)/2** ... without MUL, add n to itself for (n+1) times (use Carry for 2byte operation), then divide the result by 2 ... which is a simple shift operation

Comment: you can further optimize by determining if n is odd/even an d take out factor 2 from either n or (n+1)

Comment: _calculate the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to n_ need not be the same as _sum up all natural numbers from 1 to n_. (And _algorithm_ should essentially be independent of language.)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is
        ADD R18,R24 //sumL += nL
        ADC R19,R25 //sumH += nH + Carry

and for 2 bytes variable the max sum will be 65535 so for
1+2+3+...+n=n*(n+1)/2 <= 65535  then N <= 361 = 0x0169
1+2+3+...+361=361*362/2=65341

and code will looks like this:

```
//CPU: ATmega128A
.include "m128Adef.inc"

.DSEG 
//.ORG 0x100
n: .BYTE 2      // define 2 bytes var
result: .BYTE 2 // define 2 bytes var

.CSEG
.ORG 0
    RJMP boot

n0: .DW 0x0169 //init value for n=361 (max value for 2 byte result)

//in: N=R24:R25
//out: Sum=R18:R19
//calc sum 1 to n (n >=1 and n <=361)
//1+2+3+...+n=n*(n+1)/2 <= 65535 => n<=361= 0x0169
Sum1toN:
    LDI R18,0x00 //sumL=0
    LDI R19,0x00 //sumH=0
Lsum:
    ADD R18,R24 //sumL + = nL
    ADC R19,R25 //sumH += nH + C
    SBIW R24,0x01 //n--
    BRNE Lsum // n >0 ?
    RET

boot:
    CLR R1
    OUT SREG,R1 //Clear all

    //init stack pointer
    LDI R28,LOW(RAMEND)  //LDI R28,0xFF
    LDI R29,HIGH(RAMEND) //LDI R28,0x10
    OUT SPH,R29
    OUT SPL,R28

//init
    LDI ZL,LOW(n0<<1)
    LDI ZH,HIGH(n0<<1)

    LDI XL,LOW(n)
    LDI XH,HIGH(n)

    LDI R24,2
    LDI R25,0
init:
    LPM R0,Z+
    ST X+,R0
    SBIW R24,1  
    BRNE init 

//calc:
    LDS R24,n   // LDS R24,0x0100
    LDS R25,n+1 // LDS R25,0x0101
    RCALL Sum1toN
    STS result,R18
    STS result+1,R19

main:
    RJMP main
```